# Why self-phase modulation can prevent mode-locking?

Tags: laser, non-linear-optics

Several sources claim that Self-Phase Modulation (SPM) can prevent mode locking (ML) in fiber lasers (e.g. [rp-photonics](https://doi.org/10.61835/pqf)). I have experience of a silica fiber laser based on active ML where steady state is achieved until the optical pump rate reaches a certain threshold. Below this threshold the laser output pulses are Gaussian, periodic in shape, and the spectrum is Gaussian as well. Above that threshold, consecutive laser output "pulses" do not have the same shape, the "pulses" are longer with a not well defined shape (so not periodic) and the spectrum is not Gaussian, much broader and quasi-Lorentian. In short, ML is not obtained. All this can indeed be due to SPM.

My question is: what is the physics behind this behavior? Why, when SPM reaches a certain level, mode-locking is not possible any longer?